# replace a value for grouped rows only

Tags: mysql

I have the following sample data:

| Date | amount | type | grouping_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 10 | 1 |  |
| 2021-03-04 | 15 | 3 |  |
| 2021-03-16 | 32 | 4 |  |
| 2021-03-16 | 1 | 2 | a |
| 2021-03-16 | 4 | 3 | a |
| 2021-03-16 | 48 | 4 | a |

and my expected result is:

| Date | amount | type | grouping_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 10 | 1 |  |
| 2021-03-04 | 15 | 3 |  |
| 2021-03-16 | 32 | 4 |  |
| 2021-03-16 | 53 | 9 | a |

with the following query:

```
SELECT date, SUM(amount), type, grouping_value 
FROM table
GROUP BY date, grouping_value
```

The query is still untested but should work for all requirements but one.
As you can see from the results, the query should group by date and grouping_value. So the first three rows of my input data will remain as they are, the other three will be grouped in one movement. What I want to do is: **when some rows are grouped show 9 as type instead of one of the types that are grouped. If a row is not grouped then show the original type**.
The condition to group is that grouping_value is not blank.
How can I tell mysql to replace if it is grouping only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(*)` to tell if the row is in a group.

```
SELECT date, SUM(amount), IF(COUNT(*) > 1, 9, MAX(type)) AS type, grouping_value 
FROM table
GROUP BY date, grouping_value
```

Comment: so count(*) will tell me if the row is the aggregation of more than one row?

Comment: It tells you how many rows are were aggregated.

Comment: great! This is an use of count i was not aware of!